# why is mongoose TTL deleting document, even when partial filter does not match the option

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

my partial filter is deleting document, but user is not matching that requirement, am I using partial filter incorectly?

Thanks

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title: { type: String },
        description: { type: String },
        image: { type: String },
        price: { type: String },
        location: { type: String },
        image: { type: Array },
        author: {
            type: String,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        authorPremium: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
            index:true
        },
        reported: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        reportClear: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);

// users who are not premium will have posts deleted after 20 seconds
postSchema.index({ createdAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 20, partialFilterExpression: { authorPremium: false } });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

partial filer should not allow the authorPremium which is true to be deleted, but only delete is authorPremium is false... please advise.

return from mongo index

```
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "test.posts"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "createdAt" : 1
                },
                "name" : "createdAt_1",
                "ns" : "test.posts",
                "expireAfterSeconds" : 120,
                "background" : true
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "authorPremium" : 1
                },
                "name" : "authorPremium_1",
                "ns" : "test.posts",
                "background" : true
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "timestamps" : 1
                },
                "name" : "timestamps_1",
                "ns" : "test.posts",
                "expireAfterSeconds" : 20,
                "background" : true
        }
]
```

it seems when I use mongo cmd some of my old setting remained.. and some new? So how can I completly clear these old ttl settings when I am testing and ensure only the ones I want are there?

Comment: Can you check if your index has been created successfully on your collection?

Comment: @mickl , I am not sure how to do that, I gave up and just tried to add a ttl option to delete a post after 14 days, but it is deleting it after a few mins! I scoured the docs, and all forums, really lost here. 

this is what I am trying now ```postSchema.index({createdAt: 1},{expireAfterSeconds: 60*60*24*14});
```

Comment: Try to open mongo shell and run `db.posts.getIndexes()` (assuming that your collection name is `posts`) to see if partialExpression is there - your code looks valid

Comment: I will update post with the return but it seems it is keeping my old schema index configurations even though I set it to some new ones as you just saw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `.index(...)` does not work because you already have old index on `createdAt` field and mongoose won't drop the old one. To synchronize the indexes with your schema you can use [Model.syncIndexes](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.syncIndexes)

More on how `.index()` works and why `.syncIndexes()` was introduced can be found [here](http://thecodebarbarian.com/whats-new-in-mongoose-5-2-syncindexes).

Comment: I tried to use it, but I did not create a model, I created a schema, you can see my design, I tried to use the cmd to talk to the scema but I got errors...

Comment: I think I will remove ttl functionality, does not make sense to me, cannot find explanations, seems too buggy and just not work, I can make a simple query to delete a post if timestamp older than  x days for user x and user y, its a good concept ttl but in my opinion its too unreliable and unstable.

Comment: You cannot talk to the schema from cmd since schema is something mongoose-specific. `module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);` is the moment when you create the model, you can also drop old indexes manually from mongo shell to get your new ones created but I would recommend using `syncIndexes`

Comment: where would I use sync index, inside somewhere I have imported the model?

Comment: yes, you can run it once when you import your model and your app starts

Comment: hmm, I tried this in my post route, but its saying collection is undefined of the model.. I hate to bug you about this, but this just makes my point very clear, where is the clear explanation from mongoose about using ttl properly... its a fringe concept .. ```const postModel = require('../models/postModel');
const userModel = require('../models/userModel');

if (postModel !== null) {
 postModel.syncIndexes()
}```